# should we set ItemsSource again or update view model

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, observablecollection, itemssource

I have a view model (an `ObservableCollection` list) set as `ItemsSource` for a `ListBox`. When I refresh this view model (get new data from network), should I set `ItemsSource` again, or just let it notify the `ListBox` ?

Which solution gains the most performance ?

P/S: Answer targeting Windows Phone 7 is prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your ListBox`s ItemSource set to an ObservableCollection there is nothing you need to do. Just add/remove items to/from the ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Yamamoto i do not thinks so but there is absolutely no reason you should do it in your case

Comment: I see when setting ItemsSource, the ListBox take some longer to render than updating view model

Comment: Erm, why do you want to set ItemsSource again?? It defeats the point of Silverlight's powerful binding functionality. I'd say definitely don't do it unless you need to specifically work around an issue. What Igor says above is correct.